# Create groups of 3 records within ID column grouping

Tags: python, sql, pandas, window-functions

I want to create groups of 3 consecutive records within another group that I already have in the dataset. The data will be sorted as per datetime and the already present group.

Also, I want to get the maximum datetime within the group of 3 records as described below.

Below example will clear out what I need -

| Datetime | ID | Group of 3 | Max Time in group of 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-10 12:12:11 | 0 | 1 | 2022-08-10 12:13:11 |
| 2022-08-10 12:12:14 | 0 | 1 | 2022-08-10 12:13:11 |
| 2022-08-10 12:13:11 | 0 | 1 | 2022-08-10 12:13:11 |
| 2022-08-10 12:15:11 | 0 | 2 | 2022-08-10 12:15:11 |
| 2022-08-10 12:18:11 | 1 | 3 | 2022-08-10 12:21:11 |
| 2022-08-10 12:20:11 | 1 | 3 | 2022-08-10 12:21:11 |
| 2022-08-10 12:21:11 | 1 | 3 | 2022-08-10 12:21:11 |
| 2022-08-10 12:24:11 | 2 | 4 | 2022-08-10 12:29:11 |
| 2022-08-10 12:29:11 | 2 | 4 | 2022-08-10 12:29:11 |
| 2022-08-10 12:34:11 | 3 | 5 | 2022-08-10 12:34:11 |

Any SQL or Pandas solution will be appreciated. I tried using SQL window functions but couldn't get the logic right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a SQL solution using `row_number()` and integer-math to group by threes and choosing the max value for each group.

```
select  Datetime    
       ,ID
       ,max(Datetime) over(partition by id, grp3) as mx_grp3
from   (
       select *
              ,(row_number() over(partition by id order by Datetime)-1)/3 as grp3
       from   t 
       ) t
```

| Datetime | ID | mx_grp3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-10 12:12:11.000 | 0 | 2022-08-10 12:13:11.000 |
| 2022-08-10 12:12:14.000 | 0 | 2022-08-10 12:13:11.000 |
| 2022-08-10 12:13:11.000 | 0 | 2022-08-10 12:13:11.000 |
| 2022-08-10 12:15:11.000 | 0 | 2022-08-10 12:15:11.000 |
| 2022-08-10 12:18:11.000 | 1 | 2022-08-10 12:21:11.000 |
| 2022-08-10 12:20:11.000 | 1 | 2022-08-10 12:21:11.000 |
| 2022-08-10 12:21:11.000 | 1 | 2022-08-10 12:21:11.000 |
| 2022-08-10 12:24:11.000 | 2 | 2022-08-10 12:29:11.000 |
| 2022-08-10 12:29:11.000 | 2 | 2022-08-10 12:29:11.000 |
| 2022-08-10 12:34:11.000 | 3 | 2022-08-10 12:34:11.000 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1YUYUUXQ)

Comment: how to do this in pandas, if you know?

Answer (score 0):

the way I like to approach this is to put the result of the aggregate into a separate dataframe, then merge back with the original:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['2022-08-10 12:12:11',0,1],
    ['2022-08-10 12:12:14',0,1],
    ['2022-08-10 12:13:11',0,1],
    ['2022-08-10 12:15:11',0,2],
    ['2022-08-10 12:18:11',1,3],
    ['2022-08-10 12:20:11',1,3],
    ['2022-08-10 12:21:11',1,3],
    ['2022-08-10 12:24:11',2,4],
    ['2022-08-10 12:29:11',2,4],
    ['2022-08-10 12:34:11',3,5],
], columns=['Datetime', 'ID', 'Group of 3'])

maxdf = df.groupby('ID')['Datetime'].max().reset_index().rename(columns={'Datetime':'Max Time in group of 3'})

df = df.merge(maxdf, on=['ID'])
df

    Datetime    ID  Group of 3  Max Time in group of 3
0   2022-08-10 12:12:11 0   1   2022-08-10 12:15:11
1   2022-08-10 12:12:14 0   1   2022-08-10 12:15:11
2   2022-08-10 12:13:11 0   1   2022-08-10 12:15:11
3   2022-08-10 12:15:11 0   2   2022-08-10 12:15:11
4   2022-08-10 12:18:11 1   3   2022-08-10 12:21:11
5   2022-08-10 12:20:11 1   3   2022-08-10 12:21:11
6   2022-08-10 12:21:11 1   3   2022-08-10 12:21:11
7   2022-08-10 12:24:11 2   4   2022-08-10 12:29:11
8   2022-08-10 12:29:11 2   4   2022-08-10 12:29:11
9   2022-08-10 12:34:11 3   5   2022-08-10 12:34:11
```

Comment: Group of 3 is a column I want to create and is not present in the input. Here, it seems you are using that as an input.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Max Time` column as follows:

```
df['Max Time'] = df.groupby(['ID', df.index // 3], as_index=False)['Datetime'].\
                     transform('max')
```

and `Group of 3` as follows:

```
df['Group of 3'] = np.where(df['Max Time'].duplicated(keep='first') == False, 1, 0).cumsum()
```